# Can't boot up with ddr3 2400mhz ram set to 2400mhz

Tags: boot, memory, overclocking, ddr3, xmp

I have ddr3 Ram 2400mhz (F3-2400c11d-16gab) but I can't boot up with preset xmp set to 2400mhz but I can boot up when I set frequency to 2200mhz.
Motherboard: P8Z77-V DELUXE
CPU: I7 3770
Please help.
Thank you for the advices.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your motherboard does not seem to support RAM at 2400 Mhz.

The [P8Z77-V DELUXE manual](https://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1155/P8Z77-V_DELUXE/E7163_P8Z77-V_Deluxe.pdf), page 2-6, says this:

> **Due to lntel 2nd generation processors**' behavior, DDR3 2200 and above, 2000/ 1800 MHz memory module **will run at DDR3 2133/1866/1600 MHz frequency as default**.

This means that the actual limitation is caused by your CPU, not by
the motherboard itself.

In addition, the very dependable Crucial website gives only 1600 Mhz
RAM upgrades for the
[P8Z77-V DELUXE](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/asus/p8z77-v-deluxe).

You may download and run the
[Crucial System Scanner](https://www.crucial.com/)
that will scan your motherboard and do a precise analysis of its
capabilities, for a second opinion.
The results given by the scanner may be counted
upon to be very accurate.

If the results are the same, then 2200 Mhz is actually pretty good.

Comment: It says 2nd generation. I7 3770 is 3rd generation - this supports up to 2600mhz

Comment: Try Crucial and you will know for sure.

Comment: It gives only 1600mhz upgrades because crucial doesn't produce ddr3 ram with higher frequency anymore.

Comment: The final capabilities are a sum of the motherboard and CPU. 2200 is already more than says the motherboard manual.

Comment: 1.) The manual says that it supports up to 2600mhz.                                                       2.) How it is possible that the crucial listed this ram: https://ibb.co/TYG99WW as compatible when the manual says: "This motherboard does not support DIMMs made up of 512Mb (64MB) chips or less 
(Memory chip capacity counts in Megabit, 8 Megabit/Mb = 1 Megabyte/MB)." so it is not very accurate.

Comment: 3.) It probably doesn't work due to cpu. Manual: "The 2400MHz memory modules above are supported on Intel®
 3rd generation processors by this 
motherboard; however, the actual frequency support varied depending on the O.C. margin of the 
installed CPU."